# Fortran simplify writing in multiple languages

Tags: function, fortran, format, arguments

I have a code that writes a lot of messages in the following way:

```
    select case(params%langue)
    case('english')
        write( *, 1124 ) dt_old, dt_new
        write( 2, 1124 ) dt_old, dt_new
1124    format(/,'adjustement of the time step:', &
            /, 'previous dt=',es10.3,', new dt=',es10.3)
    case default
        write( *, 124 ) dt_old, dt_new
        write( 2, 124 ) dt_old, dt_new
124     format(/,'ajustement du pas temps:', &
            /,'ancien dt=',es10.3,', nouveau dt=',es10.3)
    end select
```

The messages can be more or less complicated, include integers or reals such as above, or be simple strings, but the structure is always the same: 4 write statements and 2 format definitions.

The code is very large (> 100 files), and very talkative (we sometimes have hundreds of lines dedicated to writing messages in the way it is written above. These very detailed output are useful for us but they sometimes make it hard to understand what the code is doing because important lines are buried under dozens of writing statements

My question is: **is there a way to modernize or simplify this way of writing things ?**

I thought about defining all the format somewhere in the code and then pass the label of the format to a function, as well as the variables that must be printed, if any.
However, after some research, it seems that there is no such thing as passing a format label to a function in Fortran and passing an unknown number of variables of unknown type.
Can you help me ?

**Edit 1:**

A precision on what I would like to have:

I would like to be able to replace above code by something like this:

```
1124    format(/,'adjustement of the time step:', &
            /, 'previous dt=',es10.3,', new dt=',es10.3)
124     format(/,'ajustement du pas temps:', &
            /,'ancien dt=',es10.3,', nouveau dt=',es10.3)

        call dialog( 1124, 124, old_dt, new_dt )
```

where the subroutine `dialog` takes the two format labels as argument, and potentially some additional variables that must be included in the message.

Comment: Welcome, please take the Welcome [tour] and read [ask]. Your question is quite open-ended. It might actually be more on-topic at https://codereview.stackexchange.com It is not much clear to me what kind of modernization would you have in mind.

Comment: Not sure I totally understand what you want. Format labels, indeed all labels, are very old fashioned. Is there anything wrong with building the format up as a character variable and using that, dispensing with the label entirely?

Comment: OK - you can't do it with labels. A label only has a meaning in the scope it is in - outside of that subroutine/function/whatever there is no way to reference it.

Comment: Ok, I don't specifically want to keep the labels, but I want to place the write statements inside a routine. Your previous solution with the format generator could have been part of the solution, but I still need a solution to pass an unknown number of arguments with unknown types :)

Comment: Would `g0` edit descriptor simplify things for your use case? just define a generic format like `character(*), parameter :: format = "(*(g0.3,:,' '))"` and use it everywhere.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into it.

Comment: According to this explanation ("I thought about defining all the format somewhere in the code and then pass the label of the format to a function"), is it also an option to modify the codes to some extent? (If so, an alternative approach might be to define an array of format strings and use the array index (rather than statement labels).)

Comment: Yes, it would be also a solution.

Comment: Honestly, in a case like this, I would go for a more solid approach.
Define a type named `MessageProvider` and declare a module-static object of it so I can import from anywhere. In this type, I'd have methods that give me either message text or format for any of my business-case messages. I can then set up this object once at the beginning of my program, if I want the instance with messages in english, or french, or klingon.

Comment: I think I will go for this solution, thank you !